# What is the 'N' when you are dealing with SQL such as (N'')

Tags: sql, t-sql

Just like in the question, not sure what the difference between `''` and `N''` in SQL.

Comment: possible duplicate of [N prefix before string in Transact-SQL query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217535/n-prefix-before-string-in-transact-sql-query)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's shorthand for `Nvarchar`. Using that notation tells the parser to treat the following string data as `nvarchar` instead of the default `varchar`.

Example:

```
SELECT N'This is a test'; -- NVarChar data
SELECT 'Test is a test'; -- VarChar data
```

Comment: It stands for "National" I believe.

Comment: @MartinSmith You're right - *National Language Character*. So weird.

Answer (score 2):

`N` stores `UNICODE` data just like `NVARCHAR` and `VARCHAR`

An `nvarchar` column can store any Unicode data. A `varchar` column is restricted to an 8-bit codepage. Some people think that `varchar` should be used because it takes up less space. I believe this is not the correct answer. Codepage incompatabilities are a pain, and Unicode is the cure for codepage problems. With cheap disk and memory nowadays, there is really no reason to waste time mucking around with code pages anymore.

Comment: +1 A little off-topic, but I'm with you on using `nvarchar` by default. In some cases where I know I'm only storing something like a product code, or state abbreviation I'll fall back on `varchar` instead.

Comment: But as Celko says, you give someone a `NVARCHAR` column and eventually it will get a Buddhist sutra in Chinese Unicode.

Answer (score 1):

N'' indicates a unicode String.